# Numerous Unions, Easier Way?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using the query below and am getting the results I want, I just can't help but think that there is probably a better way than to repeat that code over and over with a different where clause? Recommendations?

```
WITH HHSUMMARY
AS
(
SELECT
    B.HouseholdId, SUM(B.Balance) AS AUM, SUM(B.TradeRevenue + B.TrailRevenue + B.AdvisoryRevenue) AS Revenue

    FROM
        BookSegmentation.BookSegmentationDataset B

    WHERE
        B.RepName = 'Rep'

    GROUP BY
        B.HouseholdId
)

SELECT
    '< 25K' AS [ACCT BALANCE CAT],
    COUNT(HouseholdID) AS HH,
    CAST(COUNT(HouseholdId) AS DECIMAL(18,2))/(SELECT CAST(COUNT(HouseholdId) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [% HH],
    SUM(AUM) AS [HH AUM],
    SUM(AUM)/(SELECT SUM(AUM) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [HH AUM %],
    SUM(Revenue) AS REVENUE,
    SUM(Revenue)/(SELECT SUM(Revenue) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [% REV],
    SUM(Revenue)/SUM(AUM) AS [EFFICIENCY %]
    FROM HHSUMMARY
    WHERE AUM < 25000

UNION

SELECT
    '25K-50K' AS [ACCT BALANCE CAT],
    COUNT(HouseholdID) AS HH,
    CAST(COUNT(HouseholdId) AS DECIMAL(18,2))/(SELECT CAST(COUNT(HouseholdId) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [% HH],
    SUM(AUM) AS [HH AUM],
    SUM(AUM)/(SELECT SUM(AUM) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [HH AUM %],
    SUM(Revenue) AS REVENUE,
    SUM(Revenue)/(SELECT SUM(Revenue) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [% REV],
    SUM(Revenue)/SUM(AUM) AS [EFFICIENCY %]
    FROM HHSUMMARY
    WHERE AUM >= 25000 AND AUM < 50000

UNION

SELECT
    '50K-100K' AS [ACCT BALANCE CAT],
    COUNT(HouseholdID) AS HH,
    CAST(COUNT(HouseholdId) AS DECIMAL(18,2))/(SELECT CAST(COUNT(HouseholdId) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [% HH],
    SUM(AUM) AS [HH AUM],
    SUM(AUM)/(SELECT SUM(AUM) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [HH AUM %],
    SUM(Revenue) AS REVENUE,
    SUM(Revenue)/(SELECT SUM(Revenue) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [% REV],
    SUM(Revenue)/SUM(AUM) AS [EFFICIENCY %]
    FROM HHSUMMARY
    WHERE AUM >= 50000 AND AUM < 100000

UNION

SELECT
    '100K-250K' AS [ACCT BALANCE CAT],
    COUNT(HouseholdID) AS HH,
    CAST(COUNT(HouseholdId) AS DECIMAL(18,2))/(SELECT CAST(COUNT(HouseholdId) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [% HH],
    SUM(AUM) AS [HH AUM],
    SUM(AUM)/(SELECT SUM(AUM) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [HH AUM %],
    SUM(Revenue) AS REVENUE,
    SUM(Revenue)/(SELECT SUM(Revenue) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [% REV],
    SUM(Revenue)/SUM(AUM) AS [EFFICIENCY %]
    FROM HHSUMMARY
    WHERE AUM >= 100000 AND AUM < 250000

UNION

SELECT
    '250K-500K' AS [ACCT BALANCE CAT],
    COUNT(HouseholdID) AS HH,
    CAST(COUNT(HouseholdId) AS DECIMAL(18,2))/(SELECT CAST(COUNT(HouseholdId) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [% HH],
    SUM(AUM) AS [HH AUM],
    SUM(AUM)/(SELECT SUM(AUM) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [HH AUM %],
    SUM(Revenue) AS REVENUE,
    SUM(Revenue)/(SELECT SUM(Revenue) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [% REV],
    SUM(Revenue)/SUM(AUM) AS [EFFICIENCY %]
    FROM HHSUMMARY
    WHERE AUM >= 250000 AND AUM < 500000

UNION

SELECT
    '500K-750K' AS [ACCT BALANCE CAT],
    COUNT(HouseholdID) AS HH,
    CAST(COUNT(HouseholdId) AS DECIMAL(18,2))/(SELECT CAST(COUNT(HouseholdId) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [% HH],
    SUM(AUM) AS [HH AUM],
    SUM(AUM)/(SELECT SUM(AUM) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [HH AUM %],
    SUM(Revenue) AS REVENUE,
    SUM(Revenue)/(SELECT SUM(Revenue) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [% REV],
    SUM(Revenue)/SUM(AUM) AS [EFFICIENCY %]
    FROM HHSUMMARY
    WHERE AUM >= 500000 AND AUM < 750000

UNION

SELECT
    '750K-1MM' AS [ACCT BALANCE CAT],
    COUNT(HouseholdID) AS HH,
    CAST(COUNT(HouseholdId) AS DECIMAL(18,2))/(SELECT CAST(COUNT(HouseholdId) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [% HH],
    SUM(AUM) AS [HH AUM],
    SUM(AUM)/(SELECT SUM(AUM) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [HH AUM %],
    SUM(Revenue) AS REVENUE,
    SUM(Revenue)/(SELECT SUM(Revenue) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [% REV],
    SUM(Revenue)/SUM(AUM) AS [EFFICIENCY %]
    FROM HHSUMMARY
    WHERE AUM >= 750000 AND AUM < 1000000

UNION

SELECT
    '1MM-5MM' AS [ACCT BALANCE CAT],
    COUNT(HouseholdID) AS HH,
    CAST(COUNT(HouseholdId) AS DECIMAL(18,2))/(SELECT CAST(COUNT(HouseholdId) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [% HH],
    SUM(AUM) AS [HH AUM],
    SUM(AUM)/(SELECT SUM(AUM) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [HH AUM %],
    SUM(Revenue) AS REVENUE,
    SUM(Revenue)/(SELECT SUM(Revenue) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [% REV],
    SUM(Revenue)/SUM(AUM) AS [EFFICIENCY %]
    FROM HHSUMMARY
    WHERE AUM >= 1000000 AND AUM < 5000000

UNION

SELECT
    '> 5MM' AS [ACCT BALANCE CAT],
    COUNT(HouseholdID) AS HH,
    CAST(COUNT(HouseholdId) AS DECIMAL(18,2))/(SELECT CAST(COUNT(HouseholdId) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [% HH],
    SUM(AUM) AS [HH AUM],
    SUM(AUM)/(SELECT SUM(AUM) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [HH AUM %],
    SUM(Revenue) AS REVENUE,
    SUM(Revenue)/(SELECT SUM(Revenue) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [% REV],
    SUM(Revenue)/SUM(AUM) AS [EFFICIENCY %]
    FROM HHSUMMARY
    WHERE AUM >= 5000000

UNION

SELECT
    'TOTAL' AS [ACCT BALANCE CAT],
    COUNT(HouseholdID) AS HH,
    CAST(COUNT(HouseholdId) AS DECIMAL(18,2))/(SELECT CAST(COUNT(HouseholdId) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [% HH],
    SUM(AUM) AS [HH AUM],
    SUM(AUM)/(SELECT SUM(AUM) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [HH AUM %],
    SUM(Revenue) AS REVENUE,
    SUM(Revenue)/(SELECT SUM(Revenue) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [% REV],
    SUM(Revenue)/SUM(AUM) AS [EFFICIENCY %]
    FROM HHSUMMARY
```

here are my results:

[image]

Comment: You need `GROUP BY` on a case expression and the total can be done with grouping sets or rollup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way.  You can define the group in the CTE, and then use the group with `GROUP BY`:

```
WITH HHSUMMARY AS (
      SELECT B.HouseholdId, SUM(B.Balance) AS AUM,
             SUM(B.TradeRevenue + B.TrailRevenue + B.AdvisoryRevenue) AS Revenue,
             (CASE WHEN SUM(B.BALANCE) < 25000 THEN '<25000'
                   WHEN SUM(B.BALANCE) < 50000 THEN '25K-50K'
                   . . .
              END) as [ACCT BALANCE CAT]
      FROM BookSegmentation.BookSegmentationDataset B
      WHERE B.RepName = 'Rep'
      GROUP BY B.HouseholdId
    )
SELECT COALESCE([ACCT BALANCE CAT], 'Total'),
       COUNT(HouseholdID) AS HH,
       CAST(COUNT(HouseholdId) AS DECIMAL(18,2))/(SELECT CAST(COUNT(HouseholdId) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [% HH],
       SUM(AUM) AS [HH AUM],
       SUM(AUM)/(SELECT SUM(AUM) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [HH AUM %],
       SUM(Revenue) AS REVENUE,
       SUM(Revenue)/(SELECT SUM(Revenue) FROM HHSUMMARY) AS [% REV],
       SUM(Revenue)/SUM(AUM) AS [EFFICIENCY %]
FROM HHSUMMARY
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( ([ACCT BALANCE CAT]), () );
```

Notice the use of `GROUPING SETS` to calculate the total.  You can also use `ROLLUP`.

Comment: The three subqueries used as divisors really should be pulled out into a (single) second CTE.

Comment: Thanks for your time Gordon, that is just what I needed, although I need to order it properly, low cat to high cat, total at bottom. I tried placing 'N. ' in front of my Acct Balance Cat values and the highest possible number with the total, but I really would rather not display the numbers in my output. Additionally, if a bucket doesn't contain a row, the number is skipped and it looks funny.

Comment: @Gavin . . . Try adding `ORDER BY MIN(AUM)`.

Comment: I removed my changes and added your suggestion @Gordon, it sorted right with the exception of the total, which it placed in the 2nd row.

Comment: @Gavin . . . Hmmmm . . . then you need `order by (case when [ACCT BALANCE CAT] is not null then 1 else 2 end), min(aum)`.  I think there might be a simpler method, but that is what comes to mind right now.